# React 2 components of same Class in a switch, moving from 1 to another, doesn't render again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, react-router, render

So this is my Switch:

```
   <Switch>
      <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}`} to={`${match.url}/faq`} />
      <Route exact path={`${match.url}/faq`} component={FAQPage} />
      <Route path={`${match.url}/troubleshooting`} component={FAQPage} />
      <Redirect from={`${match.url}/*`} to={`${match.url}/faq`} />
    </Switch>
```

My FAQPage is a component that has a list, which shows data from REDUX, based on the type of the list:

```
  let listType = 'troubleshooting';
if (this.props.match.url.indexOf('faq') !== -1) {
  listType = 'faq';
}
```

Where I have a ListContainer which contains the react-semantic-UI List which will populate the data.

My problem is that, if I load a page, I will get back data, and show it, but when I move to the other page. It will not Re-render the listContainer, which means it will not fetch the data, so it will show empty.
If I force reload, then my second page will load, but when I move to the first one, I get the empty data.

IF I copy paste the code of my component, and create another component to put in the second Route of the Switch. Something like:

```
<Switch>
  <Redirect exact from={`${match.url}`} to={`${match.url}/faq`} />
  <Route exact path={`${match.url}/faq`} component={FAQPage} />
  <Route path={`${match.url}/troubleshooting`} component={TroubleShootingPage} />
  <Redirect from={`${match.url}/*`} to={`${match.url}/faq`} />
</Switch>
```

This will work, assuming because the component is a different one, so it's not reused, so it has to render completely.

My question is: Is it possible to force my FAQPage to reload, from the SWITCH?
So that it will always show the correct data? (I could just leave the code with 2 exactly the same .js files, but I do not want to have redundancy like that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help. Your scenario is little hard to understand, would you consider adding minimal example on codesandbox.io